# duplicated Ubuntu app

Tags: software-center, vlc

[this is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNlIv.png)

so I tried installing vlc with the software center, it installed something that does nothing when I click on the app. so I just tried the terminal, turns out VLC was not installed, so I ran sudo apt install vlc and it worked. but now I have a problem, I have two VLC apps, one that works and other that doesn't, I have tried a dozen things and nothing works, and I think I ruined my installation of VLC because now none of them work.  If I run vlc in the terminal it just says "snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks"

also, the software center doesn't work, so I can't remove the first VLC from there. any ideas? kind of a linux noob here.

Comment: You seem to have installed both the .deb and snap versions.  The current situation with two different sources of the same package is very confusing. No one can know what the 'dozen things' you did are unless you tell us, so no one can help with that part. Suggest looking up the terminal commands to list and remove snaps. Then uninstall everything you did and start fresh.

Comment: @OrganicMarble a dozen things may be an exagerations, basically I removed and installed from the terminal a bunch of times, then I installed synaptic and tried removing everything with vlc in the name. oddly, after I did that if I wrote "vlc" in the terminal, it coudln't find the binaries, as opposed to not being installed, like it should. and then when I reinstalled everything I removed I started to get that snap error, tried running "sudo snap remove vlc" and it said snap "vlc" is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've installed the snap version of VLC and the apt version.

1. the first thing I would do is to remove the snap version with `sudo snap remove vlc` in the terminal.
2. since the apt version is not working either, I would remove it too with `sudo apt remove vlc` in the terminal.
3. There is a third option of installation, which is the flatpak version. You can install it with `flatpak install flathub org.videolan.VLC`.

Probably you will have VLC working as a flatpak now. If you don't manage to install with the third option (flatpak), you may not have the flatpak package manager installed. You can install it with `sudo apt install flatpak` in the terminal and then run the third option code.

Your software center is not working either, right. You probably have the snap software center version. So, you can install another one, with `sudo apt install gnome-software gnome-sofware-plugin-flatpak`. This one is the gnome version with flatpak. You can remove the version that is not working with `sudo snap remove snap-store`.

Comment: thanks! I tried running sudo snap remove vlc but it said it's not installed. I'd rather avoid using things like flatpak or snap, don't those things work like installers in windows? I kinda switched to linux to get away from those things. maybe managing installations is something a bit beyond of a noobs posibilities, also I just noticed, that the sofware center disapeared from the application menu at the genome desktop.

Comment: Try installing gnome-software without flatpak with `sudo apt install gnome-software`. Then you may be able to manage your packages from there. Always do backups in your system in cases like this. Install Timeshift. It restores your system without touching your files. That helps a lot when your system gets messed up.

Comment: You can also try finding vlc in your system with `dpkg --list | grep vlc`. That will show you every package with vlc. When you have the full name of the package, you can remove it with `sudo apt remove --purge packagename`. The purge will remove all the dependencies of the unwanted package.

Comment: so I installed the gnome-software, installed VLC and it worked! thank you so much. here's an odd thing that happened, I already had the VLC icon among the apps, after I installed it from the gnome center I didn't get a second icon, it's just one app, and not only that! if I run it from the terminal, it just works. I was getting ready to erase the casper-rw folder and start from scratch but I've been saved, thank you very much :D